# What are the well-known UIDs?

Tags: unix

According to the `useradd` manpage, UIDs below 1000 are typically reserved for system accounts.

I'm developing a service that will run as its own user. I know that well-known ports can be found in `/etc/services`.

Is there a place where I can find out what well-known UIDs are out there? I would like to avoid crashing with someone else's UID.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for http://serverfault.com.

Comment: I thought it might be at first, but it's not the sysadmin's job to pick the UIDs of the programs he or she installs. It's the developer's (or package maintainer's) job.

Comment: Actually, if the package developer mandates a specific UID or GID for their software (other than requiring root privileges), it is broken.  For any value you choose, someone, somewhere, will be using your chosen UID (or GID) for something, and will be unwilling to change it to accommodate your software (and I don't blame them).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [Unix and Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`getpwent(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwent) iterates through the password database (usually `/etc/passwd`, but not necessarily; for example, the system may be in a NIS domain).  Any UID known to the system should be represented there.

For demonstration, the following shell fragment and C code both should print all known UIDs on the system.

```
$ getent passwd | cut -d: -f3
```

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    struct passwd *pw;
    while ((pw = getpwent()))
        printf("%d\n", pw->pw_uid);
}
```

UID 0 is always root and conventionally UID 65534 is `nobody`, but you shouldn't count on that, nor anything else.  What UIDs are in use varies by OS, distribution, and even system -- for example, many system services on Gentoo allocate UIDs as they are installed.  There is no central database of UIDs in use.

Also, `/etc/login.defs` defines what "system UIDs" are.  On my desktop, it is configured so that UIDs 100-999 are treated as system accounts, and UIDS 1000-60000 are user accounts, but this can easily be changed.

If you are writing a service, I would suggest that the package installation be scripted to allocate a UID as needed, and that your software be configurable to use any UID/username.

Comment: Could you either edit this to mention your comment on Bane's answer above or log that as a new answer? That seems to be the real answer to my question - that the system UIDs are not common across unix/linux distributions, so the problem cannot be solved. I'd like to accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post, but since I am here in 2017, still trying to answer a similar question I thought this additional information was relevant for anyone else in the same position.

The concept of "Well known UIDs" stems back to the early days of unix, before there were multitudes of distributions and unix variants. "Well known" UIDs were considered to be those for system users like adm, daemon, lp, sync, operator, news, mail etc, and were standard across all the various systems in order to avoid uid clashes. These users are still present in modern unix-like operating systems.

Standardising uid's across an organisation is the key to avoiding these problems. As was pointed out in a comment above, these days any uid you choose is likely to be in use 'somewhere', so the best a sysadmin can aim for is to ensure that uid's are standard across all the systems that they maintain, then allocating a new uid for an application becomes simple.

To that end, for many years I have found the post linked below invaluable, and sadly there are not a lot of similar posts on the topic, and what's out there is hard to find.

[UNIX/Linux: Analyzing user/group UID/GID conflicts](https://web.archive.org/web/20180420155349/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/unix_linux_analyzing_user_group_uid_gid_conflicts1?lang=en)

If you search that blog under the 'uid' tag there are other relevant posts, including a script to automate the process of standardising uid's across multiple hosts under Linux.

This [User ID Definition](http://www.linfo.org/uid.html) is also an invaluable resource.

The short answer is, that it doesn't really matter which uid's you use, as long as they are unique and standard across your organisation, to avoid clashes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure such a list exists. How about just noting that UID's are in use through the **/etc/passwd** file, **/etc/shadow** file, and the **NIS global user list**, noting what ones are in use? Then use one that isn't!

Comment: Well, those are the UIDs that are in use on my system, but not all the UIDs that might be out there. For instance, I don't have tomcat installed, but it uses UID 91.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, that is configured in `/etc/login.defs`. Sometimes, when I install a Debian-based system, I change the "uid start" option (I forget its name, I'm not on Linux now) from 1000 to 500 for consistency with the other, Red Hat-y machines.

`man login.defs` should give you all the info you want.